# How could I use Java Input/Output streams to make my eclipse .jar game work?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, io

I spent the last 10 hours trying to solve **jar file issues**, I know I have to change code to make both my game works in Eclipse and the jar file, but I can't manage to do it !

I have a **resources source folder** in which we can find the **res** package containing a .png and a package **sounds** of .wav.

I have this **resources** and **res** folders in the folder where I put the jars as all-in jar file generated even more errors.

I tried many different solutions found on the net, such as *Class.class.getResourceAsStream*, *MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream*, *getClass().get*..., I used *InputStreamReader* for reading a file and *OutputStreamWriter* for writing in it but this does not work in both Eclipse and jar while a simple PrintWriter works in Eclipse only.

Here is, for instance, one of the methods which gives *NullPointerException* at Windows command prompt when running jar file with the java -jar x.jar command:

```
public static ArrayList<String> loadScores(){
        createFile("./resources/res/scores.txt");
        ArrayList<String> scoresInfos = new ArrayList<String>();

        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        try {
            isr = new InputStreamReader(Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/scores.txt"));
            //fileReader = new FileReader("./resources/res/scores.txt");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String line;
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);) {
            line = br.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                scoresInfos.add(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scoresInfos;
    }
```

Create file looks like this, I do write a "0" to avoid the emptiness of the file:

```
private static void createFile(String path){
    try{
        File file = (new File(path));
        if(file.exists()) return;

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");
        writer.println("0");
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

So the loadScores method works in Eclipse but when I launch the jar (generated with Eclipse and then JarSplice for the main class) I get :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at toolbox.Save.loadScores(Save.java:53)
        at gameTester.Game.loadScores(Game.java:103)
        at gameTester.Game.<init>(Game.java:64)
        at gui.Menu.main(Menu.java:177)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at toolbox.Save.loadScores(Save.java:61)
        at gameTester.Game.loadScores(Game.java:103)
        at gameTester.Game.<init>(Game.java:64)
        at gui.Menu.main(Menu.java:177)
```

Which is aiming this line :

```
isr = new InputStreamReader(Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/scores.txt"));
```

I also have same type of issues using Audio,

```
AudioInputStream ais =
                AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                    Class.class.getResourceAsStream(s)
                );
```

works very well in Eclipse but not in the jar neither (s being the absolute path).

I sometimes manage to avoid errors on Eclipse by changing the file paths, but I never had both Eclipse and the .jar file working !

It would be awesome that someone helps me find my error(s) !

**What am I missing / doing wrong ?**

**Thanks a lot for reading !**

Comment: I think what you are missing is that resources are read-only, and are supposed to exist before the program starts to run. If you create a file, it is not the same as the resource that is in the `jar`. You can't write to a resource, and a resource is not a real file.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks ! that's interesting but in my case, where I access to files already existing in the folder where is the .jar, is it still a problem ?

Comment: Resources are **in the jar**, not in the folder where the jar is. If you want to access files that are in the same folder as the jar, you are supposed to use files, not resources. And knowing where the jar actually is is not trivial. You are not doing any of this in your program.

Comment: Part 1: Create *default* values in your resource files. Store them read only in your JAR. Which is a fancy ZIP file (it has some extra metadata). Part 2: On first run, check if a version of that resource exists in the user's home folder `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "scores.txt")` - if so use that to override the *defaults*. Part 3: On saving new scores write to the `File` from part 2.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks ! I now understand better the potential problems, I let you know if I manage to do it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic WELL ! I managed to make a runnable jar working ! However I had to let in the resources only the texture data, I moved the sounds in a classic folder and the scores.txt file in another classic folder outside the resources, so finally the jar needs the 3 folders in the one where it is to work properly. Thanks for the help ! However I do not know how to include everything properly only in the resources to have one unique jar file.